# QComboBox в заголовке QTableWidget

Tags: qt

Как поместить QComboBox в заголовок таблицы QTableWidget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задача отнюдь не тривиальна, несмотря на кажущуюся на первый взгляд простоту. Начать нужно с того, что в заголовок `QTableWidget` (да и любого другого аналогичного виджета) совсем не просто вставить что-либо, отличное от того, что там обычно присутствует. Связано это с тем, что заголовок - это не просто надпись, а множество элементов, соединённых вместе, каждый из которых имеет своё функциональное назначение, будь то стрелочка сортировки или границы для подгонки размера колонки. Нельзя не упомянуть и о различии стилей рисования. Всё это приводит к тому, что если разработчик желает серьёзных изменений взамен стандартному поведению, то ему придётся "рисовать" заголовок с нуля, включая упомянутые составные части и, разумеется, опираясь на стиль, используемый в приложении.

Для того, чтобы хотя бы начать, можно обратиться к `QTableView`, так как именно от него наследуется `QTableWidget`. В этом классе имеется возможность установки собственного горизонтального заголовка посредством вызова метода `setHorizontalHeader()`. Его аргументом является указатель на объект `QHeaderView`, в котором в свою очередь нужно унаследовать и переопределить метод `QHeaderView::paintSection()`. Например так:

```
class MyHeaderView : public QHeaderView {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MyHeaderView(Qt::Orientation orientation
            , QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR)
            : QHeaderView(orientation, parent) {}

    protected:
        virtual void paintSection(QPainter *painter
            , const QRect &rect, int logicalIndex) const;
};

void MyHeaderView::paintSection(QPainter *painter
    , const QRect &rect, int logicalIndex) const {

    QStyleOptionComboBox cbox_opt;
    cbox_opt.rect = rect;
    cbox_opt.state = QStyle::State_Active | QStyle::State_Enabled;
    cbox_opt.currentText = "tra-ta-ta";

    QApplication::style()
        ->drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, &cbox_opt, painter);

    QApplication::style()
        ->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ComboBoxLabel, &cbox_opt, painter);
}

QTableWidget tbl_wdg;
tbl_wdg.setHorizontalHeader(new MyHeaderView(Qt::Horizontal,&tbl_wdg));
tbl_wdg.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget");
tbl_wdg.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::AllEditTriggers);
tbl_wdg.insertColumn(0);
tbl_wdg.insertRow(0);
tbl_wdg.show();
```

Получилось вот такое:

[image: QComboBox в заголовке таблицы]

Всё бы хорошо, но как бы мы не щёлкали по заголовку, список не раскроется - это всего лишь статичная картинка. Чтобы её оживить, придётся обратиться к исходникам `QComboxBox`, где довольно внушительного размера код отвечает за раскрытие списка элементов в одном методе (`showPopup()`) и скрытие в другом (`hidePopup()`). Приводить весь этот код нет никакого смысла, поскольку он легко доступен и к большому сожалению нужен весь целиком, частями не обойтись.

Если нет желания заниматься рисованием и переносом кода из исходников Qt, то можно пойти на компромисс и вместо переопределения заголовка заняться подменой первой строки виджета таблицы или дерева. В конце концов, это большая экономия времени и сил в сравнении с тем, сколько придётся возиться с подменой заголовка, а затем, как вполне закономерное следствие, ещё и пытаться хоть как-то совместить часть стандартной функциональности с новоявленным внедрением. Хотя бы ту же сортировку, осуществляемую щелчком по заголовку.

Почему бы не создать второй заголовок из первой строки таблицы. Это относительно легко делается при помощи делегата:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QStyledItemDelegate>

class Delegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        //! Constructor.
        explicit Delegate(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR)
            : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {}

        virtual void paint(QPainter *painter
            , const QStyleOptionViewItem &option
            , const QModelIndex &index) const;

        virtual QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent
            , const QStyleOptionViewItem &option
            , const QModelIndex &index) const;

};

void Delegate::paint(QPainter *painter
    , const QStyleOptionViewItem &option
    , const QModelIndex &index) const {

    QStyleOptionComboBox cbox_opt;
    cbox_opt.rect = option.rect;
    cbox_opt.state = QStyle::State_Active | QStyle::State_Enabled;
    cbox_opt.currentText = index.model()->data(index).toString();

    QApplication::style()
        ->drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, &cbox_opt, painter);

    QApplication::style()
        ->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ComboBoxLabel, &cbox_opt, painter);
}

QWidget *Delegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent
    , const QStyleOptionViewItem &option
    , const QModelIndex &index) const {

    QComboBox *cbox = new QComboBox(parent);
    cbox->setGeometry(option.rect);
    cbox->addItem("my text");
    cbox->addItem("1");
    cbox->addItem("2");
    cbox->addItem("3");

    return cbox;
}
```

Подключать просто:

```
QTableWidget tbl_wdg;
tbl_wdg.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget");
tbl_wdg.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::AllEditTriggers);
tbl_wdg.insertColumn(0);
tbl_wdg.insertRow(0);
tbl_wdg.setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem("my text"));
tbl_wdg.setItemDelegateForRow(0, new ADelegate(&tbl_wdg));
tbl_wdg.show();
```

Получается вполне себе работоспособный виджет:

[image: QComboBox в ячейке таблицы 1]
[image: QComboBox в ячейке таблицы 2]